# Hibernate 3.3 compatibility jdk 7

Tags: java, hibernate, compatibility

I migrated from JDK6 to JDK7. Is the hibernate 3.3 compatible or will I have to upgrade hibernate?

Comment: We are running hibernate 3.x on jdk 7, i didn't face such issue it is compatible with jdk 7

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to update hibernate to latest 4.2.x at least. It have optimizations and many bugs fixed.